# Is it possible to make the Finder render thumbnails for images that have a custom extension?

Tags: macos, finder, preview, graphics, icon

I have several image files that were originally `.png`, but due to my own needs I changed their name to some custom extension `.xyz`.

Thankfully, I can still preview the images using the spacebar, so that's great. However, their thumbnail is blank:

[image]

Is it possible to tell Finder to render the image for files with extension `.xyz`? Note that the file contents are identical to that of a `.png` file - it's just the extension which is different for my own needs.

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.

Comment: Why change the extension? You could always append `.png` to your custom extension so the file would be `001.xyz.png`

Comment: Additionally, under "Get Info" you can "Hide Extension." So if your file is `001.xyz.png` it should appear `001.xyz` while still being recognized as a `.png` file. Not submitting this as an answer because I haven't tested it.

Comment: @njboot for game development. For example Unity will always reformat/compress any image it finds unless its extension is `.bytes`. So I can't append `.bytes` to `.png` (because then its basename includes `.png` and that just breaks filename paths in the project) or hide the extension. Yet, with the spacebar I can preview `.bytes` image files, so I assume there has to be a way to see their thumbnails as well - that would help me speedup development to find the right image visually (all images have strange names).